# Defining a constructor of a private class

Tags: constructor

Queue and airportSim classes are defined.

```
class Queue
{
    public:
       Queue(int setSizeQueue = 20);

    //Queue's contents
}

class airportSim
{
    public:
       airportSim(int setSizeRunway = 20);

    private:
       Queue airQueue;
       Queue groundQueue;

    //Other airportSim contents.
}

Queue::Queue(int setSizeQueue)
{
   //Contents of airportSim constructor supposed to come here.
}

airportSim::airportSim(int setSizeRunway)
{
    airQueue(setSizeRunway);
    groundQueue(setSizeRunway);
}
```

It says it has trouble accessing the constructors. Anyone know how to define the constructor of the queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [initialization list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6) syntax:

```
airportSim::airportSim(int setSizeRunway)
    : airQueue(setSizeRunway),
      groundQueue(setSizeRunway)
{
}
```